# skybrud.social instagram media by tag

Tags: javascript, instagram

My Instagram Wall stopped working today with an "Invalid Access Token" error.

Changed my code from

```
var service = InstagramService.CreateFromClientId(ClientId);
```

to

```
var service = InstagramService.CreateFromAccessToken(AccessToken)
```

Now i only get images from my own user and not as before all taget with eg. swag

How to change so i again can search by tag regardless whoever im authenticated with

```
//var service = InstagramService.CreateFromClientId(ClientId);
var service = InstagramService.CreateFromAccessToken("AccessToken");
var response = service.Tags.GetRecentMedia("swag", 30);

foreach (var media in response.Body.Data) {
    ....
}
```